# what are the differences between std::move and unique_ptr::reset?

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

For `std::unique_ptr`s `p1` and `p2`, what are differences between `std::move()` and `std::unique_ptr::reset()`?

```
p1 = std::move(p2);

p1.reset(p2.release());
```

Comment: TL;DR: The 2nd form is broken. Don't ever use it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The answer should be obvious from the standard's specification of move assignment in [unique.ptr.single.assign]/2:

> *Effects:* Transfers ownership from `u` to `*this` as if by calling `reset(u.release())` followed by an assignment from `std::forward<D>(u.get_deleter())`.

Clearly move assignment is not the same as `reset(u.release())` because it does something additional.

The additional effect is important, without it you can get undefined behaviour with custom deleters:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <memory>

struct deleter
{
  bool use_free;
  template<typename T>
    void operator()(T* p) const
    {
      if (use_free)
      {
        p->~T();
        std::free(p);
      }
      else
        delete p;
    }
};

int main()
{
  std::unique_ptr<int, deleter> p1((int*)std::malloc(sizeof(int)), deleter{true});
  std::unique_ptr<int, deleter> p2;
  std::unique_ptr<int, deleter> p3;

  p2 = std::move(p1);  // OK

  p3.reset(p2.release());  // UNDEFINED BEHAVIOUR!
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that for the `deleter` of `p3`, `use_free` is uninitialized?

Comment: @chaosink no, it's initialized to false, which means it will do `delete p` which is wrong for a pointer obtained from `malloc`.

Answer (score 5):

The first one is capable of warning you if there is a destructor mismatch, for example. In addition, `release()` is a very dangerous function, and your trivial example is correct but many other uses are not. It's best to simply never, ever use this function.

Comment: Could you give an example why is it sooo dangerous?

Comment: Where is it written in the standard that I am allowed to call, for example `reset()` on `p2` after a `move()`?

Comment: @Ali Since `reset` doesn't have any preconditions, you can always call it, since any move is specified to leave the moved from object in an **unsdefined but valid** state, which makes the use of any function without preconditions always valid. It's just when relying on certain preconditions (like the pointer being `nullptr`, but maybe even that is guaranteed for `std::unique_ptr` by standard) which requires you to first check the respective condition. Moving doesn't invalidate an object in any way, that's a common misunderstanding.

Comment: @Ali after any move, the object is guaranteed to be in a valid, but indeterminate state. std::unique_ptr makes a further guarantee that it will be a null pointer after being moved from.

Comment: @Ali: It's so dangerous because basically the only safe thing you can do with the return value is put it right back in another `unique_ptr<T, Del>`. Virtually anything else will lead to things like deleter mismatches, memory leaks, or double deletes.

Comment: If the deleters don't match the first one isn't just capable of  warning, it will refuse to compile. This is a Good Thing

Comment: Also, the first one will move the requisite deleter, I believe, whereas the second will make no change to any deleter state.

Comment: I think it's a bit misleading to call `release()` "dangerous" and advise people to never use it.  The `reset(release())` idiom is dangerous for the reasons given, but the semantics of `release()` are clear and I don't see that it's inherently dangerous.

Comment: @jb: The semantics of `release()` are clear- that you're throwing away the automatic safety of `unique_ptr` and hoping that you manually remember to take care of everything correctly yourself for every case, and if not, you're screwed in a variety of fun ways. Nope, not dangerous at all..

Answer (score -2):

The second version might not be exception safe, I think. It is equivalent to:

```
auto __tmp = p2.release();
p1.reset(__tmp);
```

Thus if the call to `std::unique_ptr::reset` throws (which may be the case if the deletion of the managed object throws), then you have an unreferred object which won't get destroyed ever. In case of the move assignment, the `std::unique_ptr` can (and should) wait with the actual move until `p1`'s original object has been destroyed properly.

But note, that this is only a problem if the destructor of the managed object could throw, which is in nearly all cases wrong in itself, or if you use a custom deleter which might throw. So in practice there isn't usually any behavioural difference between the two code snippets.

---

**EDIT:** In the end *Jonathan* points out in his comment, that the custom deleter is required by the standard not to throw, which indeed makes the throwing of `std::unique_ptr::reset` pretty unlikely/non-conformant. But he also points out that there is another difference, in that only a move assignment also moves any custom deleters, which he has also written an answer for.

---

But disregarding actual resulting behaviour, there is a huge conceptual difference between the two. If a move assignment is appropriate, **then do a move assignment** and try not to emulate it by some other code. In fact I cannot image any reason to replace the first code snippet one-to-one by the second. *DeadMG* is right in that `std::unique_ptr::release` should only be used if you really know what you're doing and in which context you're messing with unmanaged dynamic objects.

Comment: _"So in practice there isn't usually any behavioural difference between the two code snippets._" This is not true, one moves the deleter and one doesn't. This is very important if the deleter is stateful.

Comment: Y'know, `std::unique_ptr`'s move assignment operator is specified as "Transfers ownership from `u` to `*this` as if by calling `reset(u.release())` [...]". The standard relies heavily on destructors not throwing.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Hah, right! Didn't think too much about custom deleters.

Comment: Also, deletion of the managed object must not throw exceptions, see [unique.ptr.single.modifiers]/3

Comment: @Xeo But does it also rely on deleters not throwing? In then end after *Jonathan*'s comment this standard quote seem a bit too general at all, even for an *"as if"*-sentence.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Ah Ok, makes my answer pretty useless in many parts :(

Comment: "*Requires:* If D is not a reference type, D shall satisfy the requirements of MoveAssignable (Table 22) and **assignment of the deleter from an rvalue of type D shall not throw an execption**. Otherwise, D is a reference type; `remove_reference<D>::type` shall satisfy the CopyAssignable requirements and **assignment of the deleter from an lvalue of type D shall not throw an exception**." IOW, this answer is wrong in pretty much all regards. :)

Comment: @Xeo That talks about the asignment of the deleter and not its invocation. *Jonathan* already gave the correct standard reference for this.