# C++ multiple threads and vectors

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector

I tried various implementations of the following algorithm but always ended up with a crash after a while the program runs...

I have a base object

```
class Element
    {
    public:
        int a;
        float p;
        Element(int _a, float _p=1.0): a(_a), p(_p){};
    };
```

of which I create a vector and include in a Buffer object.

```
class Buffer
    {
    public:
        Buffer(){};

        vector<Element> raw;       
        vector<Element> optimised; // DATA CALCULATED BASED ON RAW

        void addElement(int _a,float _p=1.0) // FILL THE RAW BUFFER
        {
            raw.push_back(Element(_a,_p));
        }

        void compute()  // COMPUTE THE OPTIMISED BUFFER
        {
            float t;
            int i;
            for(std::vector<Element>::iterator it = raw.begin(); it != raw.end(); ++it) 
            {
                optimised.push_back(Element(it->a,it->p));
                // DO SOME COMPUTATIONALLY INTENSIVE CALCULATIONS
                for(i=1; i<9999999; i++)
                    t = 9./i;
            }
        };

        void clear() // ERASE BOTH BUFFERS
        {
            raw.clear();
            optimised.clear();
        }
    };
```

I have a declaration of a single Buffer object - responsible for capturing the current data stream - and a vector of Buffer objects - behaving like a history/queue of the previously created buffers.

```
Buffer buffer;
vector<Buffer> queue;
```

The main thread is responsible of filling the buffer object and - once a series is complete - submit the buffer into the queue.
As soon as a new buffer is added to the queue a Compute() function is called on a separate thread to analyse the recently submitted data.

```
//ADD THE CURRENT BUFFER TO THE QUEUE
queue.push_back(buffer);

//RUN 'COMPUTE' IN PARALLEL/BACKGROUND ON THE LAST SUBMITTED BUFFER
std::thread t(&Buffer::compute, &queue.back());
t.detach();

//CLEAR THE BUFFER, READY FOR A NEW SERIES
buffer.clear();
```

---

The program complies fine and launches but **it crashes during execution** (sometimes after just one buffer is submitted, sometimes after a few... it generally 'works for longer' if there is only one buffer at a time in the queue).

**Do I need to use mutex locks in this situation ? If so, where ?**

**Do you have any suggestion on how to optimise the collection of the data (fill the 'buffer' object and submit it into the queue) - I think AddElement() is a bit unnecessarily expensive ?**

ANY HELP APPRECIATED!

Thanks

Comment: You don't appear to perform any synchronization whatsoever. Why not?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The OP's asking if this will be necessary. The answer is definitely Yes!

Comment: can you give me a suggestion on the kind of synchronisation I need to do? I've been trying using mutex but I still had the crashes - unless there is only one buffer/thread being computed at a time. I thought I didnt need to lock() since there's no data being shared between the threads (I copy the buffer into queue). I need this algorithm to be VERY efficient and fluid...

Comment: Move it into the queue and create another one?

Comment: You are making copies of your buffer objects. Surely you need to stop doing that. Make the queue hold pointers to the objects rather than the objects themselves.

Comment: Why? Is it because of memory optimisation or else ?

Comment: When you store copies, adding to the queue may delete objects in the list and make copies. So taking the address of an element is dangerous. Any modification of the container invalidates that address. It's also hugely wasteful to perform copies on these objects. You've stuffed them full of data. You don't want to be copying that when you don't need to.

Comment: I stll havent managed to get the structure working... Im sure I need to used a mutex to syncronise things but I cant find a good solution (that doesnt crash and is fast).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with `&queue[last]`. That gives you a pointer to where the vector currently stores the buffer. If vector reallocates (`push_back` can do that), then the pointer is invalid.

There are a few solutions to this:

- Store pointer in the `queue` vector. Something like `vector<unique_ptr<Buffer>> queue` will work (and makes sure you don't accidentally leak the memory).
- Use a datastructure that will not invalidate invalidate the pointers when modified. `list` and `deque` will work.
- Make sure the vector doesn't reallocate. You can do a `resize(x)` initially, and then keep track of the last yourself.

Update: Add a code sample. This compiles and runs fine on Coliru (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/)

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
class Buffer {};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Buffer> buffer {new Buffer()};
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Buffer>> queue;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        buffer.reset(new Buffer());
        // Do things to buffer;
        queue.push_back(move(buffer));
    }
    std::cout << queue.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: cheers.. umh how I can I then add 'buffer' (which is of type Buffer) to 'queue' (which is of type unique_ptr<Buffer>) ?

Comment: buffer will have to be a pointer as well. You can use `unique_ptr<Buffer> buffer {new Buffer() };` and then `queue.push_back(move(buffer));`.

Comment: @Sorin.. Hmm.. after you move the unique_ptr, can you reseat it and so make another new one?

Comment: @MartinJames Yes. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860219/what-are-the-differences-between-stdmove-and-unique-ptrreset for some gotchas.

Comment: @Sorin: doing `unique_ptr<Buffer> buffer {new Buffer() };` gives me a series of errors. Starting with `buffer : looks like a function definition, but there is no parameter list.`

Comment: @mαττjαĸøb That's using c++11 syntax. You should also get some errors about unique_ptr not being defined. If you don't have a c++11 compiler you can still get some use with plain old pointers (careful not to leak data). Or use queue of list for storage.

Comment: I have C++ support (Im using VS12) and indeed `unique_ptr` is defined... what else could it be? also now when using an `iterator` in a for loop I cannot access any of the functions of buffer... (`'[name of the function]' : is not a member of 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>'`)

Comment: @Sorin: could you post a code implementation of your suggestion ? I cant get it to work properly (plus Im pretty sure it needs mutex but cant find the correct locking). I am using a c++11 compiler

Comment: @mαττjαĸøb I've updated the answer with a more complete sample. As long as you don't touch the same data from multiple threads you don't need a mutex.

Comment: @Sorin now I have an accessibility problem (I presumed caused by unique_ptr) in `std::thread t(&dynamica::Buffer::compute, queue.back());` it says `'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>'`

Comment: @Sorin ... and changing the threaded function to `std::thread t(&dynamica::Buffer::compute`, move(queue.back())); (I read uniqe_ptr are movable but not copiable) compiles the app but then crashes at runtime...

Comment: use queue.back().get(). That will give you the pointer, as you had before. @mαττjαĸøb