# move() data back from thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, move, shared-memory, unique-ptr

I have a class ('Buffer')  that contains a < vector > of data and an analyze() function that does some computation on the  data ('raw' and 'optimised').

```
class Buffer
    {
    public:
        Buffer(){};

        vector<Element> raw;       
        vector<Element> optimised; // DATA CALCULATED BASED ON RAW

        [...]

        void analyze()  // COMPUTE THE OPTIMISED BUFFER
        {
            for(std::vector<Element>::iterator it = raw.begin(); it != raw.end(); ++it) 
            {
                optimised.push_back(Element(it->a,it->p));
                // DO SOME COMPUTATIONALLY INTENSIVE CALCULATIONS
                for(i=1; i<9999999; i++)
                    t = 9./i;
            }
        };
    };
```

Because I need to create a series of the above 'Buffer' objects and keep interactive framerates, I am running the analyze() function for each buffer object onto a separate thread.
The only working solution I found for this is to use unique_ptr for keeping my collection of buffer objects

```
std::unique_ptr<dynamica::Buffer> buffer; //TEMPORARY COLLECTOR
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<dynamica::Buffer>> queue; //COLLECTION OF ALL PREVIOUS BUFFERS
```

and hence use move() when passing each of these objects to the respective thread.

```
queue.push_back(move(buffer));
//RUN 'ANALYZE' IN PARALLEL IN BACKGROUND
std::thread t(&Buffer::analyze, move(queue.back()));
t.detach();
```

My problem (**I suspect**) is that after I move() my object to a new thread for doing the analyze() computation I can no loner access the variable and methods in it (once the parallel thread has finished) from the main thread.

```
//from the main thread, once I know the parallel thread doing analyze() has finished
queue[0]->someFunction() // CRASH! ERROR! BOOM!
```

PS: Here ([C++ multiple threads and vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20328052/c-multiple-threads-and-vectors/20328389?noredirect=1#comment30377403_20328389)) is a reference to how I managed to get the threading working - and why it's the only solution.

Comment: How can you know, that "thread doing analyze() has finished" if you detach it, not join?

Comment: Move it back again.  Queue it back when it's done.

Comment: @MartinJames how can I move it back ? I cant find a way to pass a link to the main thread to the calling thread so that it can move the queue back...

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a threading issue. This is a misunderstanding of move semantics I think, you have handed the queue over to the detached thread and thus no longer own it.

Edit (Example code) :

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>

class Element
{
public:
    int a;
    float p;
    Element(int _a, float _p=1.0): a(_a), p(_p){};
};

class Buffer
{
public:
    Buffer(){};

    std::vector<Element> raw;       
    std::vector<Element> optimised; // DATA CALCULATED BASED ON RAW

    void addElement(int _a,float _p=1.0) // FILL THE RAW BUFFER
    {
        raw.push_back(Element(_a,_p));
    }

    void compute()  // COMPUTE THE OPTIMISED BUFFER
    {
        float t;
        int i;
        for(std::vector<Element>::iterator it = raw.begin(); it != raw.end(); ++it) 
        {
            optimised.push_back(Element(it->a,it->p));
            // DO SOME COMPUTATIONALLY INTENSIVE CALCULATIONS
            std::cout << "Performing calculations..." << std::endl;
            for(i=1; i<9999999; i++)
                t = 9./i;
        }
    };

    void clear() // ERASE BOTH BUFFERS
    {
        raw.clear();
        optimised.clear();
    }

    const std::pair<std::vector<Element>::const_iterator, std::vector<Element>::const_iterator> someFunction()
    {
        return std::make_pair<std::vector<Element>::const_iterator, std::vector<Element>::const_iterator>(begin(optimised), end(optimised));
    }

    ~Buffer() { clear(); }
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
Buffer origin;
auto buffer = std::make_shared<Buffer *>(&origin);
std::vector<decltype(buffer)> queue;

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    (*buffer)->addElement(i);

queue.push_back(buffer);

std::thread t(&Buffer::compute, *queue.back());

t.join(); // wait for results

auto result = (*queue.back())->someFunction();

for( auto ele = result.first; ele != result.second; ele++   )
{
    std::cout << (*ele).a << std::endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: mmh Im a bit confused: I thought when passing a reference to a callable object and to an object to std::thread the values wouldnt be copied but just executed from the same position in memory. Analyze() is a member function of Buffer and what I am passing as second parameter is the object Buffer from which run the analyze() function. Hence why no parameters are needed in analyze(). ... **BUT** Im likely the confused one, so if you can please argument more your solution (esp with some code!). Thanks